# Nest 3rd gen thermostat N72 Error Does not detect Power from Rh wire

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I just hooked my Nest 3rd gen thermostat to my split heating/cooling system with a Common wire coming from the air handler in my ceiling. On my old stat I didnt use a common because it was battery powered. With everything hooked up my AC/fan is running fine but my heat won't kick on. I noticed that the Rh port shows "Power" greyed out and get a N72 error.

In my research it looks like this may be a common problem with split systems. Some people are still able to run their heat even with the error but for me I can't get the heat to run. Is this a wiring issue? Does the Heat have to somehow connect to the C wire from the AC?[image]

Comment: Can you post the make and model of your air handler/furnace as well as photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and air-handler/furnace ends please?

Comment: does connecting `W1` to `RH` start your heat?